# Does php7 apache module cache scripts?

Tags: php, apache

When php7 used as apache module, does it provide a kind of virtual machine or runtime cached script repository or it just loads and interprets php7 script every time the user request page

Comment: It depends if you have PHP's opcode cache enabled or not. Apache won't cache anything unless you tell it to.

Comment: are you looking for [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP7 without OPCache will compile script on run time.

With proper OPCache setup, there is a cache for the compiled results. And the server can use it until the script is changed / expires the way you configure it.

More on OPCache:
https://community.1and1.com/php-7/

Comment: "will use it until the script is changed" only if you configure it so.